# Run multiple prerequisite exe on Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, containers, exe, .net-4.8

I want to build a complex legacy .Net framework project on a Docker container. There are quite a few prerequisite executables to be installed before building the solution. I have created a Dockerfile with Windows Servercore 2019 base image as follows

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
WORKDIR /App
COPY . ./
RUN powershell Start-Process vld-2.5.8-setup.exe
RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-i586.exe
RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-x64.exe 
#need to install few more build tools
```

When I build the image using

```
docker build -t consoleapp_image . 
Step 1/6 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
 ---> 997b460651ea
Step 2/6 : WORKDIR /App
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 1cd3b9f95bc9
Step 3/6 : COPY . ./
 ---> 871ad7a1c8f2
Step 4/6 : RUN powershell Start-Process vld-2.5.8-setup.exe
 ---> Running in eb11a9479c64
Removing intermediate container eb11a9479c64
 ---> 8330a331897d
Step 5/6 : RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-i586.exe
 ---> Running in d95c69f4296f
Removing intermediate container d95c69f4296f
 ---> f3a1f0fe8819
Step 6/6 : RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-x64.exe
 ---> Running in 46437b28ab84
Removing intermediate container 46437b28ab84
 ---> ba2d168b87b2
Successfully built ba2d168b87b2
Successfully tagged consoleapp_image:latest
```

I could see the output as successfully built image, but I am not sure whether they have actually been installed as I am unable to find any installed folders when I tried to run the image using any of the following commands

```
docker exec -it container powershell
docker run -it consoleapp_image
```

1. Is RUN powershell Start-Process the right command to install any prerequisite?
2. I cannot see any installed folders in `C:/Program Files` or `C:/Program Files(x86)`, how do I ensure the exes are installed correctly?

Also tried silent installation, but the no installed folder found

```
RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-i586.exe -ArgumentList '/s'
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get a partial success by running jdks through the commands

```
RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-i586.exe -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
RUN powershell Start-Process jdk-7u25-windows-x64.exe -ArgumentList '/s' -Wait
```

However, the third exe vldsetup.exe didn't work in the same approach as it needs a way to accept License agreement to complete the installation. There isn't any common approach for all exes. I tried '/accepteula' but stills throws the popup license agreement. Appreciate any ideas to set license agreement to 'I accept the agreement' and continue silently. Looks like default is set to 'I do not accept the agreement'